# Named - Log NXDOMAIN queries at the server?

Tags: centos7, bind, named-conf

I've been scouring the internet for an answer to this - being new to setting up DNS, I can't believe that there's not a clear option for this.

All I'm trying to do is have `named` write to a log each time it receives a request that it can't find and has to return `NXDOMAIN`.  That's it.  It seems like that shouldn't be hard.

**named.conf**:

```
logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity debug 1;
        };
        channel errors {
                file "/var/log/named/query_errors.log";
                print-time yes;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                severity debug 2;

        };
        category query-errors {
                errors;
        };
        category unmatched {
                errors;
        };
        channel queries {
                file "/var/log/named/queries.log";
                print-time yes;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                severity debug 2;

        };
        category queries {
                queries;
        };
};
```

For some reason, the categories `query-errors` and `unmatched` don't log `NXDOMAIN` returns.

Does anyone know how I can do this with `named` and not some third party monitoring?

*Update*

I went through the documentation at:

http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#logging_statement

And then added every single logging Category to my named.conf, and dumped all of their output at debug level 3 to file.  It was 1500 lines for 3 practice DNS requests.  Not a single mention of NXDOMAIN or of a failed lookup being passed to the client.

Comment: Do you just want to log the number of `NXDOMAIN` or do you want the actual domain as well?

Comment: user3788685 is probably hinting to the fact that you will have the number of NXDOMAIN in the statistics, see http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#statistics and the `QryNXDOMAIN` counter

Comment: Thanks user3788685 - yes, I need to know the actual domain that was requested.  I'm setting up a DNS server that is authoritative for an internal zone, and I want to log requests against it that it doesn't know how to find.